# Application manifest - does it require UTF-8 BOM?

Tags: winapi, utf-8, manifest, byte-order-mark

If I am to create application manifest and embed it as resource into my application, should my `MyApplication.manifest` file contain UTF-8 BOM or not (`0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`) before compiling it as an application resource?

The same question applies if I am to use manifest file separated from the main EXE (by adding it next to main EXE e.g. MyApp.exe and MyApp.manifest)?

If you have any references to this, it would be useful, I could not find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the manifest is an XML file.  Which states the text encoding used in the rest of the file with the processing instruction:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
```

The resource compiler will embed the file as-is.  It does come to a good end if the file starts with a BOM anyway, the operating system knows how to skip it.  As long as it matches the processing instruction anyway.

Comment: Also, some resource compilers are known to fail if they encounter a BOM in a manifest resource.